# Identify specific device using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, mobile

I am writing a voting plugin for my Wordpress site. I would like for a client to be able to vote without logging in. What I have done is I have used `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to only allow each client to vote once. Since the voting also uses AJAX, the voting is quick and easy.

However, I have run into a problem with mobile devices as they don't have unique IP addresses. What solution can I use to make sure that people cannot spam the vote button (or if someone double clicks on it, that two votes are not registered etc.) on a mobile device?

This does not need to be a fool-proof method. I realize that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is not foolproof either (although if anyone has any fool-proof ideas that can be implemented easily, I'd love to hear those as well).

Comment: they have ip addresses, but its not unique.

Comment: "Apparently they don't have IP addresses." That's not true. Every device has an IP.

Comment: What's wrong with setting a cookie? Most users don't even know what cookie is, so they won't clear it.

Comment: @MightyPork Don't let the Cookie Monster know that.

Comment: Try doing a `print_r` on `$_SERVER` and seeing what values are printed for mobile devices. It might be possible that the variable name is different on mobiles.

Comment: Sorry, I was speaking quickly. I know that  have ip addresses. I meany unique addresses

Comment: hmm ok thanks for the suggestions. I will try these and report back